# How can i get a field of QuerySet

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I add post in admin panel, when i need to create qr cod from post.title text

i tried use django-qr-code library and ContactDetail model,but i get error:type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not Post

views.py
    def index(request):

```
# Use a ContactDetail instance to encapsulate the detail of the contact.
posts = Post.objects.all()
contact_detail = ContactDetail(
    first_name=Post.objects.get())    

# Use a WifiConfig instance to encapsulate the configuration of the connexion.

# Build context for rendering QR codes.
context = dict(
    posts=posts,
    contact_detail=contact_detail,

)

# Render the index page.
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context=context)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

html

```
{% qr_for_contact contact_detail=contact_detail size='S' %}
```

Comment: Appearantly, you are using `ContactDetail` of django-qr-code library. You need to provide more details from your question, we can not understand that from your current info provided.

Comment: of course what else you need?

Comment: i am adding posts from admin panel and when i need to create qr cod with from post.title

Comment: you must mention that you are using some external library and what you are expecting as a working result.

Comment: okey, i edited it